# How set command works in FOR loop of Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, set

I am new in CMD scripting. Please explain what is going on:
Script:

```
FOR %%W IN (
    aaa
    bbb
) DO (
    echo was=%%W 
    set fff=%%W*
    echo new=%fff%    
)
```

Result:

```
was=aaa
new=bbb*
was=bbb
new=bbb*
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code and that output doesn't match.

Comment: Try Copy-Paste Stephan. You will get the same result.

Comment: no, I do not. `%new%` is always empty (except it is defined before running that code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command interpreter needs to know that variables inside the loop require re-evaluation. Search for and learn about `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%W IN (
    aaa
    bbb
) DO (
    echo was=%%W 
    set fff=%%W*
    echo new=!fff!
)
```

Comment: Wow! That way works! Thank you a lot. I may use your fix. But I still confused with what happen with my code and why I need to complicate the very simple code with such strange way?

Comment: @user3994488: short demonstration of [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). See links in comment there for technical details

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any more curious things which have to be aware of the regular C, Perl, Python, ... programmer like me?

Comment: yes: batch is not a programming language, but a collection of various utilities. They evolved through decades, and therefore may not have coherent behaviour. That makes each problem a new challenge.

Comment: @user3994488 - I would like to slightly disagree with @Stephan. `cmd` is an interpretive programming language, like BASIC, Perl, and Python. That is not to say that it is a good or bad language. The trick is to choose a language appropriate, and available, for the task.